# How to perform mysqldump and import simultaneously?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump, master-slave-replication

I have a master database and a slave one. Recently, the slave has not synced with the master. So, I tried running mysqldump command to the master:

```
mysqldump -h <master_host> -u <user> -p <database_name> --databases <database_name>--triggers --routines --master-data=1 --single-transaction >> MySQLData.sql
```

And I got a file with 80GB.
Then, I ran `mysql -u <user> -p <database_name> < MySQLData.sql` to import the master data. But the disk capacity was nearly full.
Do we have any solution for this issue to avoid the full disk problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compress the file when dumping.

```
sudo mysqldump -h <master_host> -u <user> -p <database_name> --databases <database_name>--triggers --routines --master-data=1 --single-transaction | gzip >/root/MySQLData.sql.gz
```

Then import the compressed file.

```
sudo gzip -dc /root/MySQLData.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p <database_name>
```

> -d --decompress --uncompress
>
> -c --stdout --to-stdout
> Write output on standard output; keep original files unchanged.  If there are several input files,
> the output  consists  of  a  sequence  of  independently  compressed  members.  To  obtain  better
> compression, concatenate all input files before compressing them.

Comment: (aka "gunzip"?)

Answer (score 0):

I gather that the servers are so full of data that there is not enough room for a backup -- or close.  That is a bad situation to get into.  This also applies to `ALTERing` a big table, which cannot benefit from compression.

Plan A:

Don't have the dump on the same machine.

You already dump the data to some machine there than the Primary.  Perhaps that should be a third machine, not the Replica.

```
mysqldump -h Primary ... > local.sql
mysql     -h Replica ... < local.sql
```

Plan B:  (A + compression)

To add compression, too, then be sure to do it on the appropriate side of the network.  This avoids the network being the bottleneck, but *could* lead to a CPU problem.  And it probably involves ssh or having a script that is run remotely.

Plan C:

Do both steps at the same time -- thereby avoiding the 80GB file.

```
mysqldump -h Primary ... |
mysql     -h Replica ...
```

(I suspect adding gzip would unnecessarily slow down this technique.)